How to write the boundry condition using pdex4 function in MATLAB?
I don't know how why the boundry condition is written like this, could you please tell me how the original equation transformed to theseenter image description here? I don't know how to use this toolbox because I don't know how to write the function [pl,ql,pr,qr] = pdebc(xl,ul,xr,ur,t).
Thank you very much!
More information please check: http://www.ece.northwestern.edu/local-apps/matlabhelp/techdoc/ref/pdepe.html
